# Seleccionar varias filas alternas en una JTable "getSelectedRows();"

Tags: java, mysql

buen día, ojala podamos aprender del tema que estoy intentando resolverme, pero que me he atorado y no puedo resolverlo.

Ojala podamos aprender todos en este bonito foro.

Tengo la siguiente linea de código en la cual me inserta en campo de texto los datos de la fila seleccionada.

lo siguiente esta en un jpopupmenu,

```
 int fila = tbfacturas.getSelectedRow();

if (fila >= 0) {
    txtodc.setText(tbfacturas.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
    txtfactura.setText(tbfacturas.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());

} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no seleciono fila");

}
```

[image: Interfaz]

Quiero que realice selecciones múltiples y en lugar de cargar los datos en un campo de texto, invocando el método para insertar los guarde en la base de datos, solo que tengo entendido que

Una JTable por defecto trabaja en el modo MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION si no lo cambio. Los siguientes modos existen:

> ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION - Puede seleccionar solo un indice
>   ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION - puede seleccionar indices consecutivos
>   ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION - puede seleccionar sin restricción

Lo que pasa es que uso tabla.getSelectedRow() que solamente me devuelve el número de la ultima fila seleccionada. lo que busco es:

```
int[] seleccionados = tabla.getSelectedRows();
```

Pueden ayudarme-apoyarme con este método, de como invocarlo y aunque en este  momento me los devuelva en un campo de texto me ayudara mucho, pasar este bache.

Muchas gracias por todo antes que nada, y ojala que a futuro pueda compartir este conocimiento con mas personas.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes Eduardo!

Si no he entendido mal tu consulta, logras obtener el **vector de posiciones** `seleccionados`, lo que significa que en esa variable hay un arreglo unidimensional que contiene todas las filas seleccionadas, como por ejemplo `[4,5,6,7]`.

Solo te restaría armar un **bucle** y recorrerlo de esta manera.

```
for (int i= 0; i< seleccionados.length; i++){
    // usas el indice seleccionados[i] para indicar qué fila debes tratar
}
```

Adentro del for realizas la inserción. Y se debería realizar cuatro veces la misma inserción con distinta fila.

Espero haberte ayudado

Saludos!